# btrfs used size doubled after replace operation

Tags: btrfs

I had to replace a btrfs RAID1 device today. This is the filesystem status before the operation:

```
$ btrfs filesystem show /mnt
Label: none  uuid: b19e1a48-a25b-4f63-941d-c009949a5d51
        Total devices 2 FS bytes used 2.11TiB
        devid    1 size 0 used 0 path  MISSING
        devid    2 size 5.46TiB used 2.17TiB path /dev/mapper/datadungeon
```

Then I ran `btrfs replace start -r 1 /dev/mapper/eternalepoch /mnt`. I put the `-r` by mistake due to reading the wrong section, but the man pages suggest to me that it should be fine. This is the filesystem shortly after starting the operation:

```
$ btrfs filesystem show /mnt
Label: none  uuid: b19e1a48-a25b-4f63-941d-c009949a5d51
        Total devices 3 FS bytes used 2.11TiB
        devid    0 size 2.73TiB used 2.17TiB path /dev/mapper/eternalepoch
        devid    1 size 0 used 0 path  MISSING
        devid    2 size 5.46TiB used 2.18TiB path /dev/mapper/datadungeon
```

And this is the filesystem after the operation was finished (I also did a `btrfs filesystem resize 1:max /mnt`):

```
$ btrfs filesystem show /mnt
Label: none  uuid: b19e1a48-a25b-4f63-941d-c009949a5d51
        Total devices 2 FS bytes used 2.11TiB
        devid    1 size 5.46TiB used 2.17TiB path /dev/mapper/eternalepoch
        devid    2 size 5.46TiB used 4.35TiB path /dev/mapper/datadungeon
```

I ran `du -sch` on the root of device 2 mounted with `-o degraded` (hopefully giving me the results of that drive alone) and it gave me 2.17TB, as expected. So, my question is: why the hell is the reported size doubled and how do I get it back!? It's like it cloned into itself. Would a balance operation work or will it just double the size of the other device?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have any snapshots?  (btrfs subv show /mnt) - Still wouldn't really explain doubling the space, for which there seem to be reports all over on u.s.e

Comment: You've a misunderstanding how BTRFS works. Please read the official documentation. `btrfs filesystem show` shows you the general organization of your BTRFS. `devid    2 size 5.46TiB used 4.35TiB path /dev/mapper/datadungeon` tells you, that the device with id 2 has a size of 5.46 TiB and that the BTRFS filesystem spans 4.35TiB of it. So if you would export the filesystem to a file, it would need 4.35TiB space for it. `btrfs filesystem show` doesn't tell anything about the usage of the filesystem itself, there you use `btrfs filesystem du /mnt`. Also take a look at `btrfs filesystem df /mnt`.

Answer (score 0):

So, after occasionally checking the `filesystem usage` (`device usage` gives similar information to `filesystem show`), I discovered that the 2.17TB was actually very little data:

```
$ btrfs filesystem usage /mnt
Overall:
    Device size:                  10.92TiB
    Device allocated:              6.52TiB
    Device unallocated:            4.39TiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Device slack:                    0.00B
    Used:                          4.22TiB
    Free (estimated):              4.45TiB      (min: 3.72TiB)
    Free (statfs, df):             1.17TiB
    Data ratio:                       1.50
    Metadata ratio:                   1.50
    Global reserve:              512.00MiB      (used: 0.00B)
    Multiple profiles:                 yes      (data, metadata, system)

Data,single: Size:2.17TiB, Used:256.00KiB (0.00%)
   /dev/mapper/datadungeon         2.17TiB

Data,RAID1: Size:2.17TiB, Used:2.10TiB (97.22%)
   /dev/mapper/eternalepoch        2.17TiB
   /dev/mapper/datadungeon         2.17TiB

Metadata,single: Size:10.00GiB, Used:112.00KiB (0.00%)
   /dev/mapper/datadungeon        10.00GiB

Metadata,RAID1: Size:10.00GiB, Used:3.05GiB (30.50%)
   /dev/mapper/eternalepoch       10.00GiB
   /dev/mapper/datadungeon        10.00GiB

System,single: Size:32.00MiB, Used:240.00KiB (0.73%)
   /dev/mapper/datadungeon        32.00MiB

System,RAID1: Size:32.00MiB, Used:336.00KiB (1.03%)
   /dev/mapper/eternalepoch       32.00MiB
   /dev/mapper/datadungeon        32.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/mapper/eternalepoch        3.28TiB
   /dev/mapper/datadungeon         1.11TiB
```

So I ended up just doing a balance with `btrfs balance start -dprofiles=single,convert=raid1,soft -mprofiles=single,convert=raid1,soft /mnt` (I think the soft and profiles=single are redundant in this case). A few minutes later I get:

```
btrfs filesystem show /data
Label: none  uuid: b19e1a48-a25b-4f63-941d-c009949a5d51
        Total devices 2 FS bytes used 2.11TiB
        devid    1 size 5.46TiB used 4.35TiB path /dev/mapper/eternalepoch
        devid    2 size 5.46TiB used 4.35TiB path /dev/mapper/datadungeon
```

But!, filesystem usage is actually only 2.10TB:

```
Data,RAID1: Size:4.33TiB, Used:2.10TiB (48.61%)
   /dev/mapper/eternalepoch        4.33TiB
   /dev/mapper/datadungeon         4.33TiB
```

So I suppose some data just got written to the first disk before I ran the replace command, btrfs for some reason allocated 2.17TB immediately and this was all just a non-problem caused my lack of knowledge of btrfs outputs (specifically, where sometimes `used` isn't actually used, but just allocated).

Comment: I'd do a few balance runs with -musage=NN, with increasing numbers for N, for example with 0, 11, 33, 77, 99, 100, then similarly with -dusage=NN.  I have just freed 2.5GB on a 32GB filesystem this way, and before that, a random -dusage=66 balance was actually reporting out of disk space errors (8GB+, over 25% was free).  Also make sure you're using a recent kernel/btrfs-progs/distribution.

Comment: Yes, I did a balance with a high NN and it brought the values down to the expected 2.10TB.